# NavigationLink don't load my personal View correctly (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I create a CardButton View and I use this in the ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true){
                        VStack(alignment: .leading){
                            NavigationLink(destination: NewScore(), label: {
                                CardButton(textCard: "Text1", image: "image1")
                            })
                            NavigationLink(destination: ScoreSaved(), label: {
                                CardButton(textCard: "Text2",image: "image2")
                            })
                            NavigationLink(destination: Analisys(), label: {
                                CardButton(textCard: "Text13",image: "image3")
                            })

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title1"))
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

When I added the Navigation Link, the image declared in the CardButton constructor is no longer displayed, and appears a blue circle in its place.

What I wrong?

Comment: Obviously it is needed code of CardButton to answer.

Comment: I add the code below

Comment: working on Xcode 11.3 iOS 13.3

Comment: I have Xcode 11.3 but in the Deployment Info the max version of iOS is 13.2, How do you make to select 13.3 iOS version?

Answer (score 0):

The code of CardButton View:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardButton: View {
    var textCard: String
    var image: String
    init(textCard: String, image: String){
        self.textCard = textCard
        self.image = image
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack{
                Image(image)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
                    .shadow(radius: 20)
                    .frame(width:190,height: 190)
                Text(textCard)
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
            }
        }
    }
}
```